# I can't locate an element despite using correct CSS selector/XPATH and there is no iframe in html that I'm scraping. How do I get the element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriver

Below is my entire code for reference. Everything works except for the second to last line and that is what I have a question about. Here it is.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import datetime
import time

trade_date_lim = "4/10/2021"


chrome_driver = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
browser.get('https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp')

WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#TabContainer > div > div.rtq-tab-wrap > div.rtq-tab-menus-wrap > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a > span'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#firscreener-cusip'))).send_keys("STWD")
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-advanced-search-form > div.ms-finra-advanced-search-btn > input:nth-child(2)"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-agreement > input"))).click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-grid-hd > div > div:nth-child(7) > div"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-grid-hd > div > div:nth-child(7) > div"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
whole_chart = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll"))).text


parent = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ms-finra-search-results"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div')
count_divs = len(parent.find_elements_by_xpath("./div"))



for row_num in range(1):

    #gets values that I'm looking for
    symbol = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(3)"))).text
    maturity = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(7)"))).text
    moody_rating = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(8)"))).text
    sandp_rating = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(9)"))).text
    bond_yield = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(11)"))).text

    #looks to see if all values are non-empty and if moody rating and sandp rating are not equal to 'WR' and 'NR'
    if symbol.strip() and maturity.strip() and moody_rating.strip() and sandp_rating.strip() and bond_yield.strip() and moody_rating != "WR" and sandp_rating != "NR":
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(2) > div > a"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ms-bond-detail-iframe")))
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tradeHistory_link"))).click()
        browser.switch_to.default_content()
        time.sleep(10)
        #bond information has everything we need. Now we check to see the last time this bond was actually traded
        last_trade_date = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div')))
        print(last_trade_date)
```

The error that is raised is a timeout exception.

I have tried finding by CSS Selector as well as XPATH. I am using the correct formatting for each path, I believe. I couldn't find an Iframe in the html so I don't need to worry about that. I included the implicit wait `time.sleep(10)` just to make sure that the web page has loaded fully by searching. For extra good measure I included the explicit wait of `visibility_of_element_located`. I also tried using `presence_of_element_located` and `element_to_be_clickable`. I am going crazy, can anyone help?

Ross

Comment: which line is causing issue ?

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey the line `last_trade_date = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div')))` is causing problems.

Comment: I searched for #ms-glossary in the Bond Detail page and found nothing? Am i looking in the right spot? if so, there is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues...

First, change this:

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

To this:

```
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

Switching to `default_content` is only used when working in an iFrame, which is not the case here. `browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])` switches to the last opened tab

Second, your last line should be:

```
print(last_trade_date.text)
```

Instead of:

```
print(last_trade_date)
```

Prints:

```
1/15/2021
```

BTW I don't think the `time.sleep(10)` is necessary, I took it out entirely and it ran fine

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on you last if block. The thing is you have opened a new tab when you clicked on

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tradeHistory_link"))).click()
```

so you need to change the focus of web driver to that new tab :

```
driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
```

**Code :**

```
#looks to see if all values are non-empty and if moody rating and sandp rating are not equal to 'WR' and 'NR'
    if symbol.strip() and maturity.strip() and moody_rating.strip() and sandp_rating.strip() and bond_yield.strip() and moody_rating != "WR" and sandp_rating != "NR":
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(2) > div > a"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ms-bond-detail-iframe")))
        windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tradeHistory_link"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        windows_after = driver.window_handles
        new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
        driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
        #bond information has everything we need. Now we check to see the last time this bond was actually traded
        #new_window = [x for x in window_after if x != window_before][0]
        #driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
        sleep(5)
        last_trade_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div")))
        print(last_trade_date.text)
```

**O/P :**

```
1/15/2021

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I would also suggest to not create WebDriverWait object for each operation. Instead you could do something like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

and now use wait everywhere like below :

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div")))
```

In this way you can optimize your code from. You will have less space complexity.